# How to accept multiple POST requests in emulators using Appium and Flask?

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, flask, appium

This script accepts single requests at a time

```
@app.route('/verifyUpi', methods=['POST'])
def automate_payment():
    upi_id = request.form.get('upi')

    
    desired_caps = {
        "platformName": "Android",
        "automationName": "UiAutomator2",
        "noReset": True,
        "platformVersion": "10.0",
        "udid": "emulator-5556"
    }

    
    capabilities_options = UiAutomator2Options().load_capabilities(desired_caps)

    # Initialize the Appium driver
    appium_server_url = "http://localhost:4723"
    print(appium_server_url)
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=appium_server_url, options=capabilities_options)

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)  
    # time.sleep(4)
    print("here")
    driver.switch_to.active_element.send_keys(upi_id)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@text, 'VERIFY')]"))).click()
    time.sleep(2)
    user_name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR, 'new UiSelector().description("bene-name_text")')
    )).text
    bank = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR, 'new UiSelector().description("bene-vpa_text")')
    )).text
    driver.back()
    driver.back()
    return jsonify({"success": True, "message": "Account is verified",
                    "user name": user_name,
                    "Bank": bank}), 200
```

this works fine but  I want it to run on multiple emulators too.

I tried,

```
configurations = [     {"port": 4723, "udid": "emulator-5554"},     {"port": 4725, "udid": "emulator-5556"}, ] 

def try_connect_to_appium(config):
    desired_caps = {     "platformName": "Android",     "automationName": "UiAutomator2",     "noReset": True,     "platformVersion": "10.0",     "udid": config["udid"] }
    appium_server_url = f"http://localhost:{config['port']}/wd/hub"
    print(appium_server_url)
    try:     # Attempt to initialize the Appium driver with the given configuration 
       capabilities_options = UiAutomator2Options().load_capabilities(desired_caps) 
       driver =webdriver.Remote(command_executor=appium_server_url, options=capabilities_options) 
           return driver
 except WebDriverException as e:
     print(f"Failed to connect to Appium on port {config['port']} with device {config['udid']}:     {e}")     
     return None

@app.route('/verifyUpi', methods=['POST'])
def automate_payment():
     upi_id = request.form.get('upi')
     driver = None 
     for config in configurations:
        driver = try_connect_to_appium(config)
        if driver:  
           break  #Successfully connected to an Appium server

     if not driver:
       return jsonify({"error": "Unable to connect to any Appium server."}), 500 
     #existing logic to interact with the app using the driver which is mentioned above
```

but it lacks direct checks for running Appium sessions and instead relies on handling exceptions when attempting to connect.
this approach is not good as it would hang up socket by running the same script on device as soon it gets POST request. basically the function is not able to alocate the device and port.